# Problems decrypting or encrypting a rijndael hash for my CMS this is the source code in php

Tags: php, encryption, rijndael

The hash is "Y1ovOWJSeG1DNEtrQ2ZrNit2UjNLdz09" in mysql for my admin dashboard CMS, the code is below, i am unable to decrypt or encrypt in php 7,2 can someone help me please? I lost my way to generate password for my admin CMS, I'd like to make a new password

```
<?php
class Secure {
    public static function encrypt($input, $key) {
        $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB); 
        $input = Secure::pkcs5_pad($input, $size); 
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, ''); 
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND); 
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv); 
        $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input); 
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td); 
        mcrypt_module_close($td); 
        $data = base64_encode($data); 
        return $data; 
    } 

    private static function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize) { 
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize); 
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad); 
    } 

    public static function decrypt($sStr, $sKey) {
        $decrypted= mcrypt_decrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            $sKey, 
            base64_decode($sStr), 
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        );
        $dec_s = strlen($decrypted); 
        $padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s-1]); 
        $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);
        return $decrypted;
    }   
    
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it a hash or an encrypted string? Because it it's a hash, it can't be reversed/decrypted. If it's an encrypted string, please expand on the issue more than just "I am unable to". What happens when you try to encrypt it? What happens when you try and decrypt it? Invalid response? Error messages?

Comment: Hi, merry christmas first off all! it's an encrypted string used to login into my admin cms dashboard below is the source code of controller of login procedure

Comment: i found this in the code
// function for encryption decryption
 public function encryption()
 {
  $value = "ggtest";
  $key = "ELEPHANTSCANDANC"; //16 Character Key
  echo Secure::encrypt($value, $key);
  echo Secure::decrypt(Secure::encrypt($value, $key), $key);
 
 }

Comment: You still haven't explained what actually happens. You should also include what debugging you've done. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65448209/edit) your question to include all relevant code/info instead of in comments (not very readable). Also, `mcrypt` was removed in PHP 7.2. Have you installed it through [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt) or could it be that it's missing? Have you checked your error log?

Comment: Btw, is it the admin credentials that are encrypted? If yes, you should rather hash the passwords than encrypting them (unless you do that first?)

Comment: _mcrypt_ has been removed for security reasons, i.e. you should use a more reliable library, e.g. _openssl_. You can find tons of posts about this on SO. If you replace the body of the `Secure::encrypt` method with `return openssl_encrypt($input, 'aes-128-ecb', $key, 0);` you get the desired result (analog for decryption). _openssl_ implicitly uses PKCS7/PKCS5 padding (i.e. `Secure::pkcs5_pad` is not needed). However, ECB is generally an insecure mode, which does not use an IV (so why is one created?). And as mentioned before, passwords should generally be hashed rather than encrypted.